# Viewing mongo db contents from the shell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell, rest, express

I'm new to node and mongo, and having a strange problem viewing the contents of my database from the mongo shell.  I built a simple REST api and have good CRUD functionality, but even though the data seems to be saved, I can't find it from the shell.

My program is simple; I copied it from [this example](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/10/creating-a-rest-api-using-node-js-express-and-mongodb/).

There are three files: package.json, server.js (the main file), and routes/wines.js.  Mongo db is installed and configured as usual (listening on port 27017).  I can add, update, read and delete collection items from the shell with no problems.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "wine-cellar",
  "description": "Wine Cellar Application",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.x",
    "mongodb": "^1.4.19"
  }
}
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express'),
    wine = require('./routes/wines');

var app = express();

app.use(express.logger('dev'));     /* 'default', 'short', 'tiny', 'dev' */
app.use(express.bodyParser());

app.get('/wines', wine.findAll);
app.get('/wines/:id', wine.findById);
app.post('/wines', wine.addWine);
app.put('/wines/:id', wine.updateWine);
app.delete('/wines/:id', wine.deleteWine);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000...');
```

routes/wines.js (very simple REST api)

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('winedb', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Connected to 'winedb' database");
        db.collection('wines', {strict:true}, function(err, collection) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("The 'wines' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
                populateDB();
            }
        });
    }
});

exports.findById = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('Retrieving wine: ' + id);
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
        collection.findOne({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, function(err, item) {
            res.send(item);
        });
    });
};

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
        collection.find().toArray(function(err, items) {
            res.send(items);
        });
    });
};

exports.addWine = function(req, res) {
    var wine = req.body;
    console.log('Adding wine: ' + JSON.stringify(wine));
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
        collection.insert(wine, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
            } else {
                console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
                res.send(result[0]);
            }
        });
    });
}

exports.updateWine = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    var wine = req.body;
    console.log('Updating wine: ' + id);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(wine));
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
        collection.update({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, wine, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error updating wine: ' + err);
                res.send({'error':'An error has occurred'});
            } else {
                console.log('' + result + ' document(s) updated');
                res.send(wine);
            }
        });
    });
}

exports.deleteWine = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log('Deleting wine: ' + id);
    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
        collection.remove({'_id':new BSON.ObjectID(id)}, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.send({'error':'An error has occurred - ' + err});
            } else {
                console.log('' + result + ' document(s) deleted');
                res.send(req.body);
            }
        });
    });
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Populate database with sample data -- Only used once: the first time the application is started.
// You'd typically not find this code in a real-life app, since the database would already exist.
var populateDB = function() {

    var wines = [
    {
        name: "CHATEAU DE SAINT COSME",
        year: "2009",
        grapes: "Grenache / Syrah",
        country: "France",
        region: "Southern Rhone",
        description: "The aromas of fruit and spice...",
        picture: "saint_cosme.jpg"
    },
    {
        name: "LAN RIOJA CRIANZA",
        year: "2006",
        grapes: "Tempranillo",
        country: "Spain",
        region: "Rioja",
        description: "A resurgence of interest in boutique vineyards...",
        picture: "lan_rioja.jpg"
    }];

    db.collection('wines', function(err, collection) {
        collection.insert(wines, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {});
    });

};
```

When I test the api from my terminal using curl commands, I have no problems.  I can create, read and edit data from the database and it shows up just fine on my terminal.

The mongo shell, however, is a different story.  When I run "show dbs", I see my winedb database listed, but when I run queries on it, it behaves as though the database is empty:

```
> use winedb
switched to db winedb
> db.winedb.count()
0
> db.getCollection('winedb')
winedb.winedb
> db.count()
2014-10-28T00:14:26.229-0400 TypeError: Property 'count' of object winedb is not a function
> db.winedb.count()
0
> db.getCollection('winedb').find()
> db.getCollection('winedb').count()
0
```

Meanwhile curl'ing everything continues to work fine.  How can I see my data on the mongo shell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your database is called `winedb` and the collection is called `wines`, but you've been trying to find documents in the namespace `winedb.winedb` instead of `winedb.wines`. Try the following in the shell:

```
> use winddb
> db.wines.findOne()
```

Comment: Thanks wdberkeley!  Is there any chance you can recommend a good GUI for mongo as well?

Answer (score 6):

you can see following queries on [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/)
and use application like [robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) . this will give you the query too.

simple query to get collecion

```
> use winedb
> show collections or tables //this will gives you list of collection
> db.{collectionNAME}.find()
> db.{collectionNAME}.count()
> db.{collectionNAME}.find({id:''})
```

Comment: {collectionName} did you put collection name

Comment: did you see any collection list

Answer (score 1):

```
Use mongosh console. In my example case, there is not uid/pwd set

    linux# mongosh
    > show dbs
    > use your_db_name 
   in my case its ctm
    ctm > 

run following command.. it will dump all the json data. you can limit them using find () with query constraints.

    ctm > db.getCollection('sales_data').find();
    [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("64120c325d9b5b788243f182"),
        tx_id: 1,
        tx_date_time: ISODate("2023-03-15T18:19:30.146Z"),
        item_code: '1'
      }
    ]
```